# Woocommerce make product image transparent on list item hover archive page

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm tryin to make the product image transparent on archive pages when hovering the list item. I've been able to get the title and price to hide, but have yet to figure out the image while hovering the list item. I'm doing this to show the short description which is behind the image.
This is what I have so far.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover .price, .woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover 
.woocommerce-loop-product__title  {
opacity: 0;
```

}

I can get the image to go transparent when hovering the image itself, but not when hovering the list item.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img:hover {
opacity: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by hovering to li, and it's child goes transparent.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover a img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great. and welcome to StackOverflow. If you like the answer it is always a good practice to mark the answer as the selected one, by clicking the "v" mark on the side